# What is the syntax for MariaDB 'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE'?

Tags: full-text-search, mariadb

According to the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/full-text-index-overview/):

> There are no special operators, and searches consist of one or more
>   comma-separated keywords.

The search clearly does not need to be comma-separated, as replacing commas with spaces gives the same result.

I assume that it breaks the string into separate keywords, but exactly how doesn't appear to be well documented.

With my test data, these two return the same results:

`AGAINST('Quality Water Environment' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`

`AGAINST('Quality Water åîøüé!@#$%^&*()_+Environment' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`

The second search has some characters that I consider to be 'word characters' that seem to have no influence on the result.

So what exactly is accepted by this function, and what is filtered out?